# How do I share a video to instagram feed using Swift 4.2 and Xcode 11.3?

Tags: ios, swift, video, instagram, swift4.2

I have installed instagram on my iPhone and have logged in as well.
I am using following code in Swift

```
let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .video, options: fetchOptions)
if let lastAsset = fetchResult.firstObject {
    let localIdentifier = lastAsset.localIdentifier
    let u = "instagram://library?LocalIdentifier=" + localIdentifier
    let url = NSURL(string: u)!
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url as URL) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: u)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    } else {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Instagram is not installed", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

In URL types of project target settings, I have added "instagram://library" in URL schemes. Is this wrong? What should be added here? as UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL always returns false.

Comment: Are you getting any console warning? If yes add it here.

Comment: -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "instagram://library?LocalIdentifier=E9C35595-28EF-4D41-88A2-B29759410054/L0/001" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme instagram"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your `URLScheme` in `info.plist` file to the correct scheme without including anything else at the end. Modify `instagram://library` to `instagram`.

Comment: Thanks. This got fixed :) But i think wrong video is getting selected. So I would like to get one more doubt cleared. Can I share a video shared in my app's documents directory or is it compulsory to share from assets library only for instagram.

Comment: You're welcome @pz26! Note: You shouldn't be asking new questions in the comment box, it's against the guidelines. Add a new post and share the link as a new comment and I'll try to help you out.